# Copy files that have pattern in this directory and change name of file

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

Suppose I have these files in a directory

```
/var/mydir/web.php
/var/mydir/dbMuseum.php.example
/var/mydir/dbStreet.php.example
```

In Ubuntu Linux, what would be a one line command which would copy and rename all the files to the same names but without `.example` on the end?..giving the correct result:

```
/var/mydir/web.php
/var/mydir/dbMuseum.php.example
/var/mydir/dbMuseum.php
/var/mydir/dbStreet.php.example
/var/mydir/dbStreet.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a `bash` `for` construct with parameter expansion would do:

```
for f in *.example; do mv -i "$f" "${f%.*}"; done
```

---

Ubuntu has `rename` (`prename`):

```
rename -n 's/\.[^.]+$//' *.example
```

`-n` would do the dry-run, remove `-n` for actual renaming to take place:

```
rename 's/\.[^.]+$//' *.example
```

Comment: I need original file to remain. So I change the `mv` to `cp` in the loop and it does it

Comment: @Angelo Great..glad you sorted that out :)